# Update MySQL using an array

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible in PHP using MySQLi to update a table with an array without knowing the field names, how many there is and their values.

I've tried with prepared statements inserting a question mark on key and value field (?=?). I was thinking if it's possible to use () VALUES () in a update query I might have a solution but no such thing exists I guess.

Look at my script:

```
<?php
    class UserHandler {
        public function updateUserData($array, $id) {
            global $mysqli;
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET ?=? WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $array[0], $array[1], $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
    }

    $users = new UserHandler;
?>
```

I want the usage to be like this:

```
<?php
    $users->updateUserData(array(
        'firstname' => 'Wanda',
        'lastname' => 'Merritt',
        'state' => 'IN'
        'address' => '693 Pearcy Avenue',
        'zipcode' => 46625,
    ), 45);

    $users->updateUserData(array(
        'firstname' => 'Stanley',
        'lastname' => 'Lewis',
        'password' => '123123'
    ), 159);
?>
```

Comment: In the tradition of Meta, this question [is being discussed on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4ygu1e/an_edifying_example_on_how_bad_stack_overflow_is/).

Answer (score 6):

One query, with prepared statements:

```
public function updateUserData($array, $id) {
    global $mysqli;
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET ";
    $parts = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $parts[] = "`" . $key . "` = ?";
    }
    $query = $query . implode(",", $parts) . " WHERE id = ?";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;
}
```

This does assume that all values are strings.

Comment: I have removed this a the accepted answer as it is wrong. `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` needs to be called with the correct amount of parameters the first time. You cannot append params in a `foreach` loop (like in this example) as it will generate a Warning in PHP.

Comment: Interesting thing here would be to use the `...` operator that's new in PHP 5.6

Answer (score 1):

I once wrote [a PDO wrapper](https://github.com/paragonie/airship/blob/8b7edde11b5b57fcb4b46024ca2227fd3cd4fc28/src/Engine/Database.php#L707-L768) that does update/insert queries, given an array of column => value pairs. The same general strategy may be useful here too.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
public function updateUserData($array, $id)
{
    // Instead of a global, consider dependency injection and object properties?
    global $mysqli;

    if (empty($array)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Build the update query:
    $binding = '';
    $columns = '';
    $params = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $binding .= 's';
        // Note: A whitelist is better here than escaping:
        $columns .= ' `' . preg_replace('/[^a-z_A-Z0-9]/', '', $key) . '` = ?,';
        $params []= (string) $value;
    }
    $params []= $id;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
        "UPDATE users SET " . rtrim($columns, ',') . " WHERE id = ?"
    );
    $stmt->bind_param(
        $binding . 'i', 
        ...$params
    );
    return $stmt->execute();
}
```

(Where possible, I adopted the code provided in the question. I personally would tackle this problem more generically, like I did with the wrapper above, then just use the abstraction.)

This assumes all strings. You could detect the type of `$value` in the foreach loop to specify a different type placeholder if you prefer. (PHP 5.6+ only, which are the only version currently supported anyway.)

In the sample above, the strings it build should look like:

```
<?php
/*
$users->updateUserData(array(
    'firstname' => 'Wanda',
    'lastname' => 'Merritt',
    'state' => 'IN'
    'address' => '693 Pearcy Avenue',
    'zipcode' => 46625,
), 45);
*/

# Query string: 
  "UPDATE users SET  `firstname` = ?, `lastname` = ?, `state` = ?, `address` = ?, `zipcode` = ? WHERE id = ?"
# Binding:
  "sssssi"
# Parameters
  [
    'wanda',
    'Merritt',
    'IN',
    '693 Pearcy Avenue',
    '46625',
    45
  ]
```

And then:

```
/*
$users->updateUserData(array(
    'firstname' => 'Stanley',
    'lastname' => 'Lewis',
    'password' => '123123'
), 159);
*/
# Query String:
  "UPDATE users SET  `firstname` = ?, `lastname` = ?, `password` = ? WHERE id = ?"
# Binding:
  "sssi"
# Parameters:
  [
    'Stanley',
    'Lewis',
    '123123'
  ]
```

It should go without saying, but I'll say it anyway: Don't store plaintext passwords.

Comment: Instead of using `preg_replace` you should probably error out on invalid names.

Comment: That's what the comment above means; i.e. whitelist the possible values.

Answer (score 0):

A use of a Query Builder can simplify your life:

```
public function updateUserData($array, $id) {
    global $db;
    $q = new Query($db);
    $q->table('users')
    $q->set($array);
    $q->where('id', $id);
    $q->update();
    return true;
}
```

A job of a query builder is to automatically escape field names to prevent injections and to allocate parametric variables for the values.

There are many different Query Builders, I have used the syntax of [DSQL](http://git.io/dsql).

Answer (score -2):

```
$a=array("item1"=>"object1", "item2"=>"object2");


      function update_data($a, $id)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE Tbl_name SET ";
            $sql .= urldecode(http_build_query($a,'',', '));
            $sql .= " WHERE img_id='".$id."'";

             //echo $sql;//this is only for testing.  
}

echo update_data($a, $id);
```

output is: UPDATE images SET item1=object1, item2=object2

Comment: Please add a little explanation with your code as well?

Answer (score -4):

If I wanted to do such a thing, I would loop through the array, like this:

```
function updateUserData($array, $id) {
  $query = 'UPDATE `table` SET ';
  $sep = '';
  foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $query .= $sep.$key.' = "'.$value.'"';
    $sep = ',';
  }
  $query .= ' WHERE `id` = "'.$id.'"';
  // execute query
}
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't get the security benefits of prepared statements.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'm just showing how to create the query. Martijn included a loop-version of his answer, so I won't update mine.

Answer (score -4):

I am new coder. This is my solution for Update Mysql by array.
It checks if value is empty and protect against mysql injection.

```
$datas = array('column_name' => 'data');

function esemenyFeltolto(array $datas, $id){

$mysqli = getConnect();

foreach($datas as $key=>$value){

    if(!empty($value)){
         $key = $mysqli->real_escape_string($key);
         $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);

         $data[] = $key.'="'.$value.'"';
         }
    }

    $query = "UPDATE table SET ".implode(',',$data)." WHERE table_id = ".$id;
    $mysqli->query($query);
}
```